# Reports missing while printing

Tags: java, spring-boot, itext

I've an application that allows the user to send a list of documents directly to the printer. They can see the list of entries on the screen and when they click "print" the application creates them one by one and send them to the printer. It works fine, but sometimes it misses one or two form the lot.

I've created logs to see what's going on but it doesn't show anything. Below is the method that sends the document to the printer

```
public static void print(PDDocument document) throws PrinterException
{
    PrintService printer= findPrinter();

    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(document));

    job.setPrintService(printer);
    try {
        job.print();
        logger.info("sent to printer: " + printer.getName());
    }catch (Exception ex){
        logger.info("fail to send to printer: " + printer.getName());
        throw new PrinterException("Report fail to print");
    }
}
```

The logs for today are these. There are additional logs outside the method to identify the report printed. The last report printed is because it was missing from the previous lot. However, it shows as sent to the printer in the lot.

```
2020-03-05 11:44:02 INFO  EspFailureServiceManager:74 - sent to printer: \\niabps01\ACC Mono Printer
2020-03-05 11:44:02 INFO  EspFailureServiceManager:102 - This is info:  Report created with batchId 67969  and appId: 323412

2020-03-05 11:44:24 INFO  EspFailureServiceManager:74 - sent to printer: \\niabps01\ACC Mono Printer
2020-03-05 11:44:24 INFO  EspFailureServiceManager:102 - This is info:  Report created with batchId 67971  and appId: 323441

2020-03-05 11:44:50 INFO  EspFailureServiceManager:74 - sent to printer: \\niabps01\ACC Mono Printer
2020-03-05 11:44:50 INFO  EspFailureServiceManager:102 - This is info:  Report created with batchId 67972  and appId: 323688

2020-03-05 11:44:50 INFO  EspFailureServiceManager:108 - This is info: 3 reports have been created

2020-03-05 12:37:47 INFO  EspFailureServiceManager:74 - sent to printer: \\niabps01\ACC Mono Printer
2020-03-05 12:37:47 INFO  EspFailureServiceManager:102 - This is info:  Report created with batchId 67973  and appId: 321932

2020-03-05 12:37:50 INFO  EspFailureServiceManager:74 - sent to printer: \\niabps01\ACC Mono Printer
2020-03-05 12:37:50 INFO  EspFailureServiceManager:102 - This is info:  Report created with batchId 67973  and appId: 321931

2020-03-05 12:37:54 INFO  EspFailureServiceManager:74 - sent to printer: \\niabps01\ACC Mono Printer
2020-03-05 12:37:54 INFO  EspFailureServiceManager:102 - This is info:  Report created with batchId 67973  and appId: 321930

2020-03-05 12:37:56 INFO  EspFailureServiceManager:74 - sent to printer: \\niabps01\ACC Mono Printer
2020-03-05 12:37:56 INFO  EspFailureServiceManager:102 - This is info:  Report created with batchId **67973**  and appId: **321929**

2020-03-05 12:37:59 INFO  EspFailureServiceManager:74 - sent to printer: \\niabps01\ACC Mono Printer
2020-03-05 12:37:59 INFO  EspFailureServiceManager:102 - This is info:  Report created with batchId 67973  and appId: 321933

2020-03-05 12:38:02 INFO  EspFailureServiceManager:74 - sent to printer: \\niabps01\ACC Mono Printer
2020-03-05 12:38:02 INFO  EspFailureServiceManager:102 - This is info:  Report created with batchId 67973  and appId: 321924

2020-03-05 12:38:02 INFO  EspFailureServiceManager:108 - This is info: 6 reports have been created

2020-03-05 12:39:58 INFO  EspFailureServiceManager:74 - sent to printer: \\niabps01\ACC Mono  Printer
2020-03-05 12:39:58 INFO  EspFailureServiceManager:102 - This is info:  Report created with batchId **67973**  and appId: **321929**

2020-03-05 12:39:58 INFO  EspFailureServiceManager:108 - This is info: 1 reports have been created
```

Could anybody help with this please?

Comment: You have added logger in exception block and it doesn't show up any error messages. Are you sure this is right section of code where issue is occurring?

Comment: @shihabudheenk the logs show the messages after the print method within 'try'

Comment: I think there is no problem with this code, and somehow is a printer issue. Maybe a problem with the print method?

Comment: it could be. try putting loggers inside print() method and check what's missed